# bootstrap button groups not working on mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, responsive-design

I have made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q44My/ of my problem. When clicking on the buttons in a normal pc browser the buttons act normal. Clicking gets them from white to purple and clicking once again gets them from purple to white.

When doing this on a mobile device it's going wrong. Clicking once gets the button from white to purple. Clicking again it stays purple unless you click on one of the other buttons or anywhere else on the screen.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug..

You can track it here on GitHub:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12832